# WooCommerce conditional statements

Tags: php, if-statement, woocommerce

I am trying to conditionally show some content based on a few Woocommerce conditionals.

I want to show content when:

1. Not on a product page
2. Not on the checkout page
3. But, on the order received checkout endpoint

The below code is not quite working, the first 2 work correctly but the endpoint doesn't seem to work as it is part of the checkout page? Any ideas how to adjust?

```
<? if( !is_product() && !is_checkout() && is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received' ): ?>
MY CONTENT
<? endif ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the endpoint is conditional on `is_checkout()` being true, you could adjust it with an OR condition within brackets so it'll evaluate to true. If both are false the content won't show, but if either one is true it will, assuming `!is_product()` is true.

```
<? if( !is_product() && (!is_checkout() || is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received' )): ?>
```